How to Render Content in SSR with a Delayed API Response While Keeping It in the Source Code?
I'm working on a Quasar project where I use preFetch and SSR to render content on my PLP (Product Listing Page). However, one of my APIs (getTours) takes around 30 seconds to respond, causing the page to remain in a loading state (API pending) until the response is received. It's crucial for me to include the content in the source code of the page for SEO purposes.
Here is a simplified version of my preFetch function:
await Promise.all([
  getTourMetaTag(requestParams),
  getTourFaqs(requestParams),
  getTourContents(requestParams),
  getExchangeRate(),
  getDestinationCities(),
  getTours(), // This API takes 30 seconds to respond
  getHotelNames(),
  getNeighborhoods(),
])
.then(async (results) => {
  const [
    tourMeta,
    tourFaqs,
    tourContents,
    exchangeRate,
    destinationCities,
    tours,
    hotelNames,
    neighborhoods,
  ] = results;
  // Further processing...
});

The getTours API is significantly delaying the page rendering. I want to avoid blocking the page rendering due to this slow API call. Instead, I'd like to:

Render the page with placeholder or skeleton content while the getTours API is still pending.

Ensure that once the getTours response is received, the full content is available in the page's source code (important for SEO).



1 and 2 contradict each other. It's either one or another. It's unknown what getTours is, how often it should be fetched. It likely needs to be cached somehow, it's hard to suggest anything without knowing the details
